# Eliminate imaginary numbers from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, complex, filtering

If I have a list such as:

https://pastebin.com/TGjWnFUH

which has also complex numbers that starts after `{95.3282,0.0000150799}`. How can I eliminate all data sets that contained those complex numbers (all data after `{95.3282,0.0000150799}` for this case)?.

Thank you,

Comment: Maybe you want `Select[data, Head@#[[2]] == Real &]`?

Comment: Or `Select[data,Im[#[[2]]] < 10^-6 &]` to check if the imaginary part is below a threshold

Comment: Another approach is to use pattern matching, e.g., : `DeleteCases[data, {_, _Complex}]`  This looks especially elegant in operator form:  `DeleteCases[{_, _Complex}]@data`

Comment: @Joshua, if you make that an answer, I'll upvote it. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got two general ways to approach this problem in Mathematica

`Select` applies a function and preserves entries based on whether that function is true or false.  In this approach you could try something like:

`Select[data, Im[#[[2]]] < 10^-6 &]`

to select cases where the imaginary part (`Im`) of the second entry in each list item (`#[[2]]`) is less than some threshold value.

Alternatively, one can use pattern matching.  The patten `{_, _Complex}` matches any item (`_`) for the first entry in the list and `Complex` types for the second item.  In this approach you could try something like:

`DeleteCases[data, {_, _Complex}]`

It is potentially more elegant to use the operator form of `DeleteCases`, as in the following:

`DeleteCases[{_, _Complex}]@data`

(Thanks to J. M. for the motivation to write this up.)

Comment: `DeleteCases[]` is clearly the more elegant choice here, but `Select[]` is more flexible, as you have demonstrated in your first example.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
v={{95.1222,0.000134014},{95.148,0.000120065},{95.1737,0.000105897}, 
   {95.1994,0.000091497},{95.2252,0.0000768485},{95.2509,0.0000619282}, 
   {95.2767,0.0000467031},{95.3024,0.00003112},{95.3282,0.0000150799}, 
   {95.3797,-0.0000204035+2.54384*10^-6 I},{95.4055,-0.0000364388+4.57472*10^-6 I}, 
   {95.4313,-0.0000527509+6.66189*10^-6 I},{95.4571,-0.0000690327+8.74688*10^-6 I},
   {95.4829,-0.000085323+0.0000108347 I},{95.5087,-0.000101651+0.0000129291 I}, 
   {95.5345,-0.000118039+0.0000150328 I},{95.5603,-0.000134501+0.000017148 I}, 
   {95.5862,-0.00015105+0.000019276 I},{95.612,-0.000167694+0.0000214183 I}};
Take[v,Position[v,x_Complex][[1,1]]-1]
```

which instantly returns the first 9 Real items before the first Complex item.

Remember there are always at least half a dozen different ways of doing anything in Mathematica. Pick the ones that make the most sense to you, try to figure out and understand why they work because that will help you remember them and use them in the future without making too many mistakes.

Comment: Bill. Thank you! This works great !

Comment: This approach depends on the elements with complex values being grouped at the end of the list. A more general approach would be `Select[v, FreeQ[#, _Complex] &]`

Comment: His subject line was "Eliminate imaginary numbers from a list", but his description was "How can I eliminate all data after {95.3282,0.0000150799}" and he said that the first data item after that contained a complex number. So I used his description and dropped the items starting with the first complex number. Certainly if he changes his data or changes his requirements then the answer will change and if he doesn't change this then this answer does what he described. Moments after I showed this he agreed this method was satisfactory. Maybe he has changed his mind now.

Answer (score 2):

```
data // Pick[#,#[[All,2,0]],Real]&
```

For example:

```
data={{74.0202,0.000284368},
  {74.0404,0.000285019},{94.6603,0.000355035},{94.6859,0.000344053},{94.7115,0.000332932},{94.7371,0.000321672},{94.7628,0.00031027},{94.7884,0.000298723},{94.8141,0.000287028},{94.8397,0.000275184},{94.8654,0.000263187},{94.891,0.000251034},{94.9167,0.000238723},{94.9424,0.000226248},{94.968,0.000213608},{94.9937,0.000200798},{95.0194,0.000187813},{95.0451,0.000174648},{95.0708,0.000161298},{95.0965,0.000147755},{95.1222,0.000134014},{95.148,0.000120065},{95.1737,0.000105897},{95.1994,0.000091497},{95.2252,0.0000768485},{95.2509,0.0000619282},{95.2767,0.0000467031},{95.3024,0.00003112},{95.3282,0.0000150799},{95.3797,-0.0000204035+2.54384*10^-6 I},{95.4055,-0.0000364388+4.57472*10^-6 I},{95.4313,-0.0000527509+6.66189*10^-6 I},{95.4571,-0.0000690327+8.74688*10^-6 I},{95.4829,-0.000085323+0.0000108347 I},{95.5087,-0.000101651+0.0000129291 I},{95.5345,-0.000118039+0.0000150328 I},{95.5603,-0.000134501+0.000017148 I}}
```

and

```
data // Pick[#,#[[All,2,0]],Real]&
```

> {{74.0202, 0.000284368}, {74.0404, 0.000285019}, {94.6603, 0.000355035}, {94.6859, 0.000344053}, {94.7115, 0.000332932}, {94.7371, 0.000321672}, {94.7628, 0.00031027}, {94.7884, 0.000298723}, {94.8141, 0.000287028}, {94.8397, 0.000275184}, {94.8654, 0.000263187}, {94.891, 0.000251034}, {94.9167, 0.000238723}, {94.9424, 0.000226248}, {94.968, 0.000213608}, {94.9937, 0.000200798}, {95.0194, 0.000187813}, {95.0451, 0.000174648}, {95.0708, 0.000161298}, {95.0965, 0.000147755}, {95.1222, 0.000134014}, {95.148, 0.000120065}, {95.1737, 0.000105897}, {95.1994, 0.000091497}, {95.2252, 0.0000768485}, {95.2509, 0.0000619282}, {95.2767, 0.0000467031}, {95.3024, 0.00003112}, {95.3282, 0.0000150799}}

Alternatively, as [bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18890/bill) has pointed out, the following may be a valid interpretation of the OP requirement:

```
TakeWhile[data, #[[2,0]]===Real &]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data =
  {{74.2, 0.28}, {74.1, 0.29}, {95.3, -0.2 + 2.54*10^-6 I}, 
   {95.4, -0.3 + 4.57*10^-6 I}};
```

Showing some of the newer functions

Using `RealValuedNumberQ` (new in 13.3}

```
Cases[{__?RealValuedNumberQ}] @ data
```

{{74.2, 0.28}, {74.1, 0.29}}

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3}

```
First @ SequenceSplit[data, {{_, _Complex}}]
```

{{74.2, 0.28}, {74.1, 0.29}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1}

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, Position[data, {_, _Complex}]] @ data
```

{{74.2, 0.28}, {74.1, 0.29}}